# Can't connect to Samsung Galaxy Tab S with Android Studio, Windows 7

Tags: android-studio, usb, adb, device

I have a nice, new Samsung Galaxy Tab S which I'm trying to connect with Android Studio. I've enabled usb debugging on the tablet, and downloaded and installed the driver by executing "SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.45.0.exe" from "http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SM-T800NTSAXAR". The Google USB driver is installed per the Android SDK menu in Android studio. I also installed Samsung Kies and it can see the Samsung.

Still Android Studio doesn't see it - nothing shows up under the "connected devices" when I try to run the app.  Also, if I go to "Users/myName/android-sdk/platform-tools and run "adb kill-server", "adb start-server", "adb devices", it doesn't show up.

I'm running Windows 7. I did try right-clicking on "Computer", clicking on "Devices", but there was no "other" category, which theoretically would allow me to see the attached Galaxy.

Any ideas?

Comment: see if this helps http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Comment: Thank you! The key was where it said "Some manufacturers do not test their devices thoroughly which sometimes results in situations when adb works only when combined with other specific inteface. I have seen a device which would only enumerate adb interface when in MTP mode but not in PTP or Mass Storage modes." I found that setting in "notifications". When I switched to "PTP", it downloaded 3 drivers and connected immediately.

Comment: The link you pointed out was enough for me !

Comment: That worked for me as well. These little bugs are freaking annoying. I would have found this eventually...but only after a forever and a half had passed...

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553097/cannot-update-samsung-galaxy-s7-driver-to-android-driver-on-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

I found that Settings > Developer Options > USB Debugging worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to device manager and uninstall android drivers(windows 10)